# Couldn't add sitemap.xml to Google console on netlify

Tags: sitemap, netlify, google-search-console, google-console-developer

I have tried on different sites, even created special domain for tests
[image]

but on **netlify** hosting there is an error

may be it's because free domain? or hosting

> Sitemap could not be read General HTTP error

Comment: I have Netlify sites that have no issue reading my sitemap files. See answer for what I have seen the same as what you are seeing.

Comment: could you show the sitemap on Netlify, that parsed by google? may be something wrong in my sitemap format

Answer (score 1):

This error often comes up the first time, although it did fetch the `sitemap.xml` file, when there is an error in the sitemap.xml file.

Click on the line that says `Couldn't fetch` and you should be redirected to a page similar to below:

[image]

You can expand the error line and it will show you the errors.

Comment: the error explains nothing) https://gyazo.com/f5784d63dd9474c7a4d01bb7d50036e2
also it's interesting that old interface says that there are no errors)) https://gyazo.com/6a26059b2d0a6f5b524ae4b45c8af146